# How to check if a column is present in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am using rails 2.3.2

I have a parameter in which i have a field name of a table. I want to find out whether or not the field is present in the table, to prevent sql injection.

```
User.find(:all, :group => params[:group], :conditions => { :admin => false })
```

I want to make sure that the params[:group] is a field from the table before actually executing the above query.

What is the way to find out that the given field is a valid field of the table?

Comment: So group is one of your `users` table columns, right?

Comment: I want a command like `column_exists?`. But this method exists for 3.x or above rails versions.

Comment: correct params[:group] is one of the fields of the table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `has_attribute?`:

```
user = User.new
user.has_attribute?(params[:group])
```

Comment: Be aware `has_attribute?` method avaliable only in instance. So this `User.has_attribute? :foo` raise error but this work `User.first.has_attribute? :foo`.

Answer (score 3):

For instances you can use:

```
user.has_attribute?(params[:group])
```

For classes:

```
User.column_names.include?(params[:group])
```

But ActiveRecord's query-building methods like: `where`, `group`, `order`, and so on, are **safe against SQL injection as long as you don't use raw SQL queries**. 
o I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: param can have the following value `params[:group] = "name UNION SELECT * FROM users"`, which will make it vulnerable

Comment: i am not able to mark this as i have allready marked another answer. both the answers are valid, and i want to mark both. how to do so?

Comment: Theres no way, only one question is marked as answer but no problem! ;) he answered first! cheers @RichaSinha